# jQuery 3.1.1 slideToggle()/toggle() malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I read a whole lot of articles on jQuery toggle/slideToggle, and none of them seem to answer my problem, so here's my question:
I'm using jQuery version 3.1.1., and my slideToggle() (including all other toggle-related events) doesn't seem to be working (see code below).  When I click on ".register-parent", ".sign-up-parent-form" (which is also part of the "sign-up-form" class) slides out, then slides back into the "hide" mode immediately.
Is this happening because I need to include speed, callback, etc. in the parentheses or not?  I use a code editor, and it says there's nothing wrong with my code.

```
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function () {
  "use strict";
  $(".sign-up-form").hide();

  $(".register-parent").click(function () {
    $(".sign-up-parent-form").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

My HTML and CSS are [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tw11potv/1/).  Thanks so much!

Comment: your html is not correct with the javascript that it doesnt have an element with $(".register-parent")

Comment: It's in line 3 of my HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `2 .register-parent'` elements in your DOM, so the event is attached to this particular class twice. That is why, when you click once, both the events are getting triggered.

Either attach events more particularly, or use `stopPropagation` like @Super User mentioned.

Comment: Nice one. root cause of the problem.

Comment: Whoops.  I didn't notice that...I see the problem now!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stopPropagation` for this, you can update your `JS` code with following code:

```
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $(".sign-up-form").hide();

    $(".register-parent").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".sign-up-parent-form").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

for updated fiddle demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/tw11potv/3/)